# Django - Get ViewDoesNotExist on a view that isn't requested by the code

Tags: python, django

I've just finished the Django Tutorial (part 4) but when I go in to check the server after everything is finished I get this:

Caught ViewDoesNotExist while rendering: Tried results in module polls.views. Error was: 'module' object has no attribute 'results'

and the usual:

/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/django/core/urlresolvers.py in _get_callback, line 170

The point with the last bit of the tutorial is to get rid of all requests except 'vote' from views.py and I though I did right right, but apparently not.

Nowhere in the code is the view 'results' requested, from what I can see, I went through the code several times and I can't find the problem.

urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import patterns, include, url

from django.contrib import admin
admin.autodiscover()

url(r'^admin/doc/', include('django.contrib.admindocs.urls')),

url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),

from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.views.generic import DetailView, ListView
from polls.models import Poll

urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$',
        ListView.as_view(
            queryset=Poll.objects.order_by('-pub_date')[:5],
            context_object_name='latest_poll_list',
            template_name='polls/index.html')),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/$',
        DetailView.as_view(
            model=Poll,
            template_name='polls/detail.html')),
    url(r'^(?P<pk>\d+)/results/$',
        DetailView.as_view(
            model=Poll,
            template_name='polls/results.html'),
        name='poll_results'),
    url(r'^(?P<poll_id>\d+)/vote/$', 'polls.views.vote'),
)
```

views.py:

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect, HttpResponse
from polls.models import Choice, Poll
from django.shortcuts import render_to_response, get_object_or_404
from django.http import Http404
from django.template import RequestContext
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse

def vote(request, poll_id):
    p = get_object_or_404(Poll, pk=poll_id)
    try:
        selected_choice = p.choice_set.get(pk=request.POST['choice'])
    except (KeyError, Choice.DoesNotExist):
        # Redisplay the poll voting form.
        return render_to_response('polls/detail.html', {
            'poll': p,
            'error_message': "You didn't select a choice.",
        }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        selected_choice.votes += 1
        selected_choice.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('poll_results', args=(p.id,)))
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class Poll(models.Model):
    question = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField('date published')
    def __unicode__(self): 
        return (self.question)

class Choice (models.Model):
    poll = models.ForeignKey(Poll)
    choice = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    votes = models.IntegerField()
    def __unicode__(self):
        return (self.choice)
```

admin.py:

```
from polls.models import Poll
from polls.models import Choice
from django.contrib import admin

class ChoiceInline(admin.TabularInline):
    model = Choice
    extra = 3

class PollAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    fieldsets = [
        (None,               {'fields': ['question']}),
        ('Date information', {'fields': ['pub_date'], 'classes': ['collapse']}),
    ]
    inlines = [ChoiceInline]
    list_display = ('question', 'pub_date')
    list_filter = ['pub_date']
    date_hierarchy = 'pub_date'
    search_fields = ['question']


admin.site.register(Poll, PollAdmin)
```

Any help to find the problem is appreciated. :)

Comment: Full stack trace could get more information... Also have you restarted server?

Comment: Try to reproduce on a clean environment. This sounds like a buggy module somewhere in your `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: Makes me wonder if this is a hold over from an earlier state. Have you run `manage.py syncdb`; have you restarted the server; does your db structure match your `models.py`. If the db matches your `models.py` file, I'd be inclined to remove the `.pyc` files and restart apache or in another setup `pkill python` worked for me.

Comment: You need to post the full traceback, and your `urls.py` has some problems; and your `reverse` call is not correct either.

Answer (score 0):

The last line of your urlconf references `polls.views.vote`. This will cause Django to attempt to import `polls.views` and if there's any errors in that file (which there are based on the error message you got) it will fail.

Go into `polls/views.py` and find where "results" is being imported. Granted, the code you posted for your views.py doesn't have anything like that, but is that the complete file or just a snippet?